# Rounded Box shadow only at the corners

Tags: css

I want the box shadow to appear only at the corners in the rounded shape.
But the box shadow appears all along the sides. I want something like shown in the below figure.

[image]

html:

```
<div class="img">
    <img src="http://www.html5andbeyond.com/3t-JAiBqopF/uploads/2014/10/clouds-full.png" alt=""/>
</div>
```

css:

```
img {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px #777;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you'll have to use `border-image` to achieve that. Good luck!

Comment: You could save the picture as png with that shadow or with html you have to make 4 squares positioned absolute to image corners and apply box-shadow for them

Comment: Not sure where, but I've seen the same thing achieved in the past with an svg. I think it was used as the background image of a div that then contained the photo.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly but your problem can solve by its.

html

```
<div class="shadow">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x300" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.shadow {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.img {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #fff;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.shadow {
  position: relative;
}

.shadow:after,
.shadow:before,
.img:after,
.img:before{
    content: "";
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 26px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

.shadow:before,
.shadow:after{
  top: 0;
}
.img:before, .img:after {
    bottom: 6px;
}
.shadow:before{
  left: 0;
}
.shadow:after {
  right: 0;
}
.img:before {
  left: 0;
}

.img:after {
  right: 0;
}
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bae881og/1/)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create 2 pseudo elements that you'll display beneath the .img element. By rotating them 45deg in both direction you'll have rectangles for both diagonals, and then put box shadow on those to get your result

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  }
.img {
    position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
.img:before,
.img:after{
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 138%; 
  height: 60px;
  z-index: -1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}
.img:after{
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="http://idav.ucdavis.edu/~okreylos/ResDev/SplineApproximation/Examples/Lena3200G.gif" />
</div>
```

The 138% for the width is slightly less than the length of the diagonal of a square. This would need adjustments for rectangles.

Answer (score -1):

You can either create a png file using [24bit transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) or use the CSS code as it follows:

```css
div{
  width: 300px;
  position:relative;
  }

#corner1
{
  background:red;
  width:50px;
  height:10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
    <img src="http://www.html5andbeyond.com/3t-JAiBqopF/uploads/2014/10/clouds-full.png" alt=""/>
    <div id="corner1"></div>

</div>
```

As you can see you could simply hide different divs behind the image by replicating the inner #cornerN div. Of course in your case the parent div would be the container element (cloud image).

Finally, watch out for box shadows properties working across browsers: use the property "box-shadow" by remioving the -webkit prefix.